# Racket How do i remove parentheses and apostrophe from lists?

Tags: list, racket

Lets say I have a list containing arguments, how can I display it without the parentheses, example:

(define lst (list 1 2 3)) (display lst)

-> (1 2 3)

But I want it to appear as: 1 2 3

My attempt:

```
(define (clean-list lst)
  (if
    (null? lst) (display (null))
    (display (car lst)))
  (display #\space)
  (clean-list (cdr lst)))
```

It returns the the list without parentheses, but with an error message... Anyone who could help me with this? Also note that im new to racket and racket is my first programming language. Appreciates all answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you always call recursively the function, after the `if`, even when the list is null.

Here is a correct version:

```
(define (clean-list lst)
  (when (cons? lst)
    (display (car lst))
    (display #\space)
    (clean-list (cdr lst))))
```

Note that this function prints only the elements on the first level of the list without parentheses, but if an element is a list it is printed with parentheses.

Comment: Nice use of `when`. I haven't seen it used much and I really like it here.